# "list index out of range" when using random to pick item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and I wrote a program to pick a random office episode to watch and 75% of the time my program works but the other 25%, it gives me the error :

> list index out of range.

I've tried messing with the min max values in the line that chooses the episode

```
import random as r
seasons = [
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
          ]

def choose_ep():
    global seasons
    s = r.randint(1,10) # 1 - 10, not including 10 
    e = r.randint(min(seasons[s - 1]), max(seasons[s - 1]))
    print("Season: " + str(s) + ", Episode: " + str(e))

while True:
    choose_ep()
    if input() == "exit":
        break
```

I want it to give me a random episode from a random season. I don't want it to give me an episode that doesn't exist like "season 1, episode 14"

Comment: r.randint(1, 10) gives a random integer between 1 and 10 inclusive, which can be confusing compared to, say, range(1, 10) giving the range between 1 and 9. I noted the comment in your code saying you purposefully set the max to 10, but you need to set it to 9. (I put a print(s) after the s= line to see if this was the case. I can forget what randint gives, too.)

Comment: I believe `random.choice` is a better function for you to use, then you don't have to deal with indices.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

So 10 is in fact included in the values of variable `s` and hence you get your error.

Comment: @t0asty If my answer has helped you, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with no index generation:

```
import random as r

season_number, episode_list = r.choice(list(enumerate(seasons)))
season_number += 1
episode_number = r.choice(episode_list)

print(season_number, episode_number)
```